# What is the maximum EU per tick you can generate with a 6 Chambered Nuclear Reactor using only a Mark I setup?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

What is the most efficient setup for a 6 Chambered Reactor, and have it NEVER overheat.
 *Ideally I would not want the cooling components to meltdown either.*

Please note the setup is for a **SIX CHAMBERED REACTOR** not *six reactors*.

Comment: So you want a safe "Mark I" reactor?

Comment: fill it with uranium, let it run for 1 tick, replace uranium with cooling components, let run until cooled down, repeat

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I want to know how much EU per tick, with the conditions listed, I Can get from a safe mark I i suppose.

Comment: Nuclear Reactors? Damn, Minecraft is one scary game...

Comment: @Nolonar it's modded minecraft, vanilla is still a gentle game, if you don't mind the hordes of multiplying zombies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a number of hours that I'd rather not disclose, I put this together;

[image]

Note, the single Component Heat Exchanger is important. Active output is 420 EU/t, and it will run for 2 hours 46 minutes and 40 seconds, totaling at 84 million EU.

Comment: for whatever reason the link to your layout doesnt work for me.

Comment: are you using google chrome? If so, google chrome blocks that application for some reason, i'll take a screenshot and edit into the answer

Comment: Okay, the screenshot has been edited into the hyperlink to replace the un-running site, I was having the issue as well, and I learned that Java blocks it because the Java it runs is no longer compatible with Java versions 7.51 and up, and that website hasn't been updated since IC2 came out with the new nuclear reactor components. The new link is a gyazo, so it should work perfectly.

Comment: I fixed the response to correctly answer your question, sorry I misinterpreted the original question.

Comment: all those empty spaces imply this design could still be improved upon, I think ima play with it a bit :) what's the website that allows you to theorycraft this stuff?

Comment: I use the standalone version that can be downloaded from http://www.talonfiremage.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/v3/reactorplanner.html

Comment: all that does is send me to a page to download java

Comment: http://www.talonfiremage.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/v3/ICReactorPlannerV3.jar should be the direct download

Comment: Out of curiosity: *how* does that single heat exchanger prevent the vents from overheating?

Answer (score 1):

The design shown below produces a signifigant **320 eu\t** but this is the design given at the [wiki](http://ftbwiki.org/Nuclear_Reactor). I'm sure there must be a better one.

[image: 320 eu\t Mark I Reactor Design]

Comment: Is it possible for this to overheat?

Comment: Negative, this design is 100% renewable Mark I safe, the only component that ever needs to be replaced are the Fuel Rods once they deplete. (I'm using this design as we speak in IC2 Experimental)

Answer (score 1):

Note that efficiency (EU/rod) and throughout (EU/t) are not related. A high throughput reactor is not necessarily efficient.

This answer considers efficiency as total EU/rod, which is what the reactor planner app defines as efficiency.

One very efficient design is this:

[image]

`erp=AudaVNFQX9163ABic6PdxKIr3OwoiQ+toWI665/DJIi0hDTnQka+FiCVYeL96RQB`

It has an efficiency factor of 7, or **14mEU / rod** (throughput: 140 EU/t). (*)

In comparison,

- the reactor described in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/164894/235582) has an efficiency factor of 3, or **6mEU / rod**, `erp=ALnWlTRUJODL7ZAYrnsf8uA1WVN+yeK6PmbdRxXRnNrJh+YZfH3jvU17wQa2ZQ68AQ==`
- the reactor described in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/178791/235582) has an efficiency factor of 4, or **8mEU / rod**, `erp=Bc60qaKgv7r2Fa/BvWsFmfkgymWh0iBhhdK96oyrNV1x+Tku3S42XKJbutYr+E48AQ==`

In general, reflectors increase efficiency, cells increase throughout. Both increase heat.

(*) It does require 16 iridium, which is a pain to get

Note that this is can be further simplified in terms of resources required as follows: `erp=AXOtKmioL/A1q7Cqc3DRQZUfu1/3uVGMlrNLEDNT/1Irvjy76Pn+56FPmE26pIQB`